# convert time to decimal in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, time, decimal

i have a table in sql server 2012, with one of its column having the following data in time datatype,
How would you convert 00:45:00 to 0.45
or 01:45:00 to 1.45 ?

please help.

Comment: Perhaps you could make an attempt?

Comment: just a question, u know that decimal value of 1:45:00 is 1.75h? :)

Comment: You could use DATEPART() and then implement your own logic ....

Comment: I did make an attempt but to no avail. Anyway, Thanks a lot guys. I'll keep trying. Adios!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, it seems you only want to remove the ':' with '.'. If so, it can be achieved in many ways in SQL Server 2012. One example is below.

If your column is 'Datetime', use this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(DatetimeCol AS TIME),5),':',',') FROM Tbl
```

Else if it just 'Time' then remove the cast.

Answer (score 10):

You could do arithmetic such as:

```
 select cast(datepart(hour, col) + datepart(minute, col) / 100.00 as decimal(5, 2));
```

But as noted in the comments, "1.45" seems quite confusing.  Most people think this should be "1.75".  If you want the latter -- with precision to the minute -- you can do:

```
 select cast(datepart(hour, col) + datepart(minute, col) / 60.00 as decimal(5, 2));
```

Answer (score 6):

You know that decimal value of 1:45:00 is 1.75h

try this if you want to convert time to decimal

```
select  datediff(second,0,'01:45:00') / (60.0 * 60.0)
```

But if you getting value as par your requirement then try this way

```
select cast(datepart(hour, '01:45:00')+datepart(minute, '01:45:00') / 100.00 as decimal(7,4));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, if you want to do the operation based on minutes, you could do it like:

select  datediff(minute,0,'01:45:00') / 60.0

Comment: @hiral i want datediff in same as result from this select cast(datepart(hour, '01:45:00')+datepart(minute, '01:45:00') / 100.00 as decimal(7,4));

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this approach can help, but I use a simple one liner for performance monitoring:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,3), DATEDIFF(MS, DATEADD(S,0,0), [Duration_tm])/1000.0) AS [Duration_sec]
```

... turns a `TIME` to `DECIMAL` seconds.
Keep in mind though if you substitute a `TIME` type for `DATETIME`, the `DATEDIFF(MS` ... will overflow if that exceeds 24days 20h:31m:23s; i.e. the `DATEDIFF` return type `INT` upper limit (*roughly*)