# cast getdate() as time in decimal format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create an update statement that will check records for when the createdate & createtime fields are null.  I'm a little stuck on casting getdate() in a decimal format.  For instance, for 7:55am I want to cast as 7.9166.  For 4:15pm I want to cast as 16.25.

Comment: Can you explain the decimal conversion

Comment: Google: sql server time to decimal

Comment: @Prdp It's the decimal number of hours.

Comment: Why should 7:55 by .9166, specifically? I.e. is there a specific reason for four decimal places? And for rounding the last digit down rather than, as conventially done, up?

Comment: The timecreated field is actually a varchar(8) field, designed by software provider so I have no control over it.  So I have to convert the time as a decimal number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
  select cast(datepart(hour, GETDATE()) + datepart(minute, GETDATE()) / 60.00 as decimal(5, 2));
```

Same question here refer this

[convert time to decimal in SQL server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525845/convert-time-to-decimal-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Wouldn't you divide by 60, rather than 100 (there being 60 minutes in 1 hour)?

Comment: @MukeshKalgude it says I need a rep of 15 first.